# Can $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$ be $F_\sigma$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I already know that the set $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is $F_\sigma$ and (I think) its complement ($[0,1]^c \cup \mathbb{Q}^c$) can't be $F_\sigma$.

I know that $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$ is $G_\delta$ because we can do
\begin{align}
[0,1] = ((0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c) \cup ([0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q})
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
((0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c) = [0,1]^c \cap ([0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q})^c
\end{align}

All this is in $\mathbb{R}$ as a metric space with its usual distance. I know too about general topology, so if there exists some theorem that answers my question I will be grateful.

EDIT:

I don't know (and I don't care) if $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$ is $F_\sigma$. The problem was to find a subset of irrationals of $[0,1]$ with measure equal to $1$ and it must be $F_\sigma$. I know that $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$ is $G_\delta$ so it is measurable, so there exist $H \in F_\sigma$ and $Z$ with measure $0$ such that
\begin{align}
(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c = H \cup Z
\end{align}
then $H$ its pure irrational.

And I know that $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$ have measure $1$ because $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ have measure zero.

Comment: Do you know the Baire category theorem?  [or the notion of Baire space]

Comment: "I don't know (and I don't care) if $(0,1)\cap Q^c$ is $F_\sigma$".  "And I know that $(0,1)\cap Q^c$ have measure 1"... So what is your question then?

Comment: @GEdgar I didn't know about Baire category theorem, I've just read about it and I don't think (yet) how to apply it.

Comment: @MW Sorry, I've forgot to say that the subset of $[0,1]$ must be $F_\sigma$ too. I've just edited my question. My question was because if  $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$ is $F_\sigma$ then my problem was solved. But I realised that it doesn't matter if is or not $F_\sigma$ because if a set $E$ if measurable then $E = H \cup Z$ where $H$ is $F_\sigma$ and $Z$ has measure zero, and of course, $E$ and $H$ mesure the same.

Comment: @itnasx I see.  For what its worth, if you are looking for an explicit construction, you can always express the rationals as a $G_\delta$ with measure $0$ - For each $n$ you cover $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ with intervals of total length at most $\frac{1}{n}$ (easy to do with geometric series of lengths since rationals are countable), then intersect these dense open sets to get $G_\delta$ with measure $0$, then take its complement.